# ANDROID how detect my ip has changed??

Tags: android

I have an app. This app listen in a port from a server. the server send to my ip data. I need detect when my ip has changed, for example, no 3g conexion, activate WIFI. this generate a new ip, and I need to send this ip to the server for the server send me data in this new ip. The question is: how I can know when my ip has changed???

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the nw interfaces `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` and then do `getInetAddresses()`.

And something like this to get connection changed broadcasts:

```
private class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
        // ...
```

Comment: I don't need to send my new IP, because the server will receive an HTTP post, and it can know the IP, I just need that the android client know when the IP has changed. it is enough with this broadcastreceiver? thaaanks!

Comment: With the BroadcastReceiver you get a chance to act when the connection changes state. That's when you check the current ip of whichever interface you're interested in and compare to the previous ip which you have checked earlier.

Comment: I am implementing it. but how I can start the broadcast receiver?

Comment: This is a pretty decent tutorial, perhaps it can help? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 0):

you can get it by registering the `BroadcastReciever` for [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) and do something like this :

```
ConnectivityManager connMananger = (ConnectivityManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo netInfo = connMananger.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```